# Select query in json serde returns Null value for json file

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I have added the jar file of cloudera
ADD JAR hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.

**sample data**

```
{
    "_id" : "0000540a-e28c-44e3-a2bf-d579af4d43f4",
    "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2014-12-22T18:22:30.250Z"),
    "UpdatedDate" : ISODate("2015-02-12T04:23:53.326Z"),
    "AccountId" : "73f98922-c1a9-4fd9-bcbf-bcb24ea50009",
    "Url" : "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#search/paul+roberts",
    "Host" : "mail.google.com",
    "VisitTime" : ISODate("2014-12-22T17:59:51.225Z"),
    "Transition" : "link",
    "LifeTime" : 3267.0000000000000000,
    "Status" : "closed",
    "LocalTime" : ISODate("2014-12-22T17:59:51.225Z"),
    "referrer" : "",
    "tabId" : "409",
    "SiteType" : "Mail"
}
```

**I have create the table :**
create external table pof.TestForJson( id string, CreatedDate STRUCT, UpdatedDate STRUCT, AccountId string, Url string, Host string, VisitTime STRUCT, Transition string, LifeTime string, Status string, LocalTime STRUCT, DeviceId string, SubSiteType string, SiteType string, Flag string) ROW FORMAT serde 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe' 
with

```
serdeproperties("id"="_id" , "CreatedDate.date"="$.date" , "UpdatedDate.date"="$.date" , "VisitTime.date"="$.date" , "LocalTime.date"="$.date") location '/user/hive/warehouse/pof.db/testdata';
```

when I run select query got null value.

please help!